# How to change … (elipses) to ... (three periods) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, nokogiri

I'm parsing [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782.aspx) using `nokogiri`. I found there are some `…` (elipses) characters in that page and can't be removed. I want to know how to use Ruby to replace all `…` (elipses) to `...` (three periods).

BTW, you can search this string to find all `…s`

> Specifies whether ALTER TABLE

Edit:
I added my program and the error message.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'terminal-table'

def change s
    {Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text => " ", 
     Nokogiri::HTML("&quot;").text => '"',
     Nokogiri::HTML("&trade;").text => '(TM)',
     Nokogiri::HTML("&amp;").text => "&",
     Nokogiri::HTML("&lt;").text => "<",
     Nokogiri::HTML("&gt;").text => ">",
     Nokogiri::HTML("&copy;").text => "(C)",
     Nokogiri::HTML("&reg;").text => "(R)",
     Nokogiri::HTML("&yen;").text => " "}.each do |k, v|
         s.gsub!(k, v)
     end
     s
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782.aspx').read.tr("…","..."))
temp = []
doc.xpath('//div[@class="tableSection"]/table[position() = 1]/tr').each do |e|
    temp << e.css("td, th").map(&:text).map(&:strip).map {|x| x = change x; x.split(/\n/).map {|z| z.gsub(/.{80}/mi, "\\0\n")}.join("\n")}
end

table = Terminal::Table.new
table.headings = temp.shift
table.rows = temp


puts table
```

Error:

```
F:\dropbox\Dropbox\temp>ruby nokogiri.rb
nokogiri.rb:21: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
nokogiri.rb:21: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
nokogiri.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
...ary/ms189782.aspx').read.tr("í¡","..."))
...                               ^

F:\dropbox\Dropbox\temp>
```

Comment: Do you want to change "..." to "..." or do you want to change "..." to "..."?

Comment: Mike Samuel: THat's `…` (a single char) to `...` three chars.

Comment: Use the Unicode escape "\u2026" instead of a literal for the three-dots-character or see here how to specify the encoding for your source code: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably depends on the encoding of the file you're working with, but try using

```
"\u2026"
```

for the single-character 3-dots aka "[horizontal ellipsis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm)" (the one you want to replace).

Comment: `"\u0085"` is a control character, `NEL`.  The ellipsis character is `"\u2026"`.  You're probably thinking of the Windows-1252 character set.

Comment: I tried your method. The error disappears but it seems that the characters were not replaced. Weird. BTW, how do you find the code of this character?

Comment: Wow, \u2026 works like a charm!! Thanks Keith. How do you find this value of that character?

Comment: See Keith's comment above. Fixing my answer. Thanks, Keith, yes, i looked it up in the wrong place.

Comment: How to find the code: (1) if you have it in ruby, you can print it out using "p" or "inspect". Otherwise, (2) google for it (e.g. "Unicode ellipsis") or (3) check the tables in http://www.unicode.org/charts/ or http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm

Comment: @Yousui You find the value of the ellipse by running the program [uninames ellipse](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames).

Answer (score 5):

```
"It was a dark and stormy night…".gsub("…", "...")
```

Comment: Sorry, posted my answer before I saw this almost-identical one :)

Comment: @Yousui: I see. Ruby handles unicode nicely, it's those durn html character entities.

Comment: Don't forget to set your `# encoding` header to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just String#tr on it first.

```
open("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782.aspx").read.tr("…","...")
```

And run Nokogiri on that...

Comment: That would replace `…` by a single dot in Ruby 1.9 while working in 1.8. I'd use a more reliably method, I guess.

Comment: Well, it's not documented, which technically makes it undefined behaviour, I guess.

Comment: `tr` traditionally maps a single character from the first string to the corresponding single character in the second string. `'foo'.tr('fo','ab')` is `"abb"` when evaluated.

Comment: The stupid thing is: I knew that. I have no idea why I used $tr$ but I tapped it into $irb$ and it worked, so I just pasted it.