# Ruby 1.9 invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I've searched all over and tried everything but I still get:

```
invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

When doing something like:

```
some_string.gsub(/…/)
```

Even though I added this to the top of the file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Any help?

Comment: I made a quick test file and it works for me. (ruby 1.9.3). How are you running your file?

Comment: Is your editor actually saving your code in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
some_string.gsub(/\u2026/)
```

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421524/how-to-change-elipses-to-three-periods-in-ruby) for more information.

Comment: Good quick fix. But still would be nice to use the actual UTF-8 character.

Comment: Did you make sure the file was actually Unicode-encoded? You can also try to run the ruby script with the `-Ku` option

Comment: That option is actually for 1.8 and if he were using 1.8 he wouldn't even need it.

Comment: Im using 1.9.3. Textmate. The file is actually saved as UTF-8.